# Unexpected token: name (ClassName)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, vue.js, uglifyjs

I have the following ECMA 6 class and working on npm with vuejs:

```
import * as globalTypes from 'aaa/src/store/global/mutation-types.js'
import store from 'aaa/src/store/global/index.js'
import axios from 'axios'
import LoginService from './login.service.js'
const loginService = new LoginService() 

export default class RestService {

  constructor () {

    this.lockScreenIfNeeded = function (lockScreen) {
     //
    }

    this.unlockScreenIfNeeded = function () {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

In the build procedure,

```
npm run build
```

I get the following error for this class:

```
ERROR in static/js/vendor.61bb6545b80ac2f32bac.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (RestService) [static/js/vendor.61bb6545b80ac2f32bac.js:10168,6]
```

What is wrong with this class definition? Or should there be some extra steps taken before building vue project to avoid such errors?

Comment: Are you sure that your uglify version supports ES6?

Comment: no, how can I check it (and update it)?

Comment: i see now that ES6 is -probably- [not supported](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js) How can I avoid using uglify to build my vuejs project?

Comment: Remove it from the build script?

Comment: you can try excluding your "aaa/src.." in webpack config under "test: /\.js$/" object

Comment: Use Babel. Babel is good. It transpiles any ES6 code into readable JS.